# Leaflet maps: how to center and zoom the map on 1 marker?

Tags: leaflet

I have leaflet maps with 1 marker, like [this example](https://www.weert.nl/werkzaamheden-via-raeka-kampershoek-2-0-maandag-20-t-m-24-november). How do i change the code to center the map on this marker and change zoom-level? Can't figure out, please help! Thanks in advance...

I've tried adding .getcenter():

```
   // MARKEERPUNTEN OPHALEN
    var markerGroup = L.featureGroup([
    {string.htmldecode($markers, true)}
    ]).addTo(map);
    
    // MARKEERPUNTEN TONEN IN KAART  
    // Check the number of markers in the FeatureGroup
    function checkMarkerCount() {
    var markerCount = markers.getLayers().length; // Get the number of markers in the FeatureGroup
    if (markerCount === 1) {
        **// If there is only one marker, adjust the zoom level
        // map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds()).getCenter(); // Automatically zoom to fit the marker
        map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds().getCenter());**
    
        }
    }   

    // Call the checkMarkerCount function initially and whenever markers are added/removed
    checkMarkerCount();
```

I'll tried adding the code

map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds());

but it's not working. See [this link](https://www.weert.nl/werkzaamheden-via-raeka-kampershoek-2-0-maandag-20-t-m-24-november)

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the ".getCenter()" part, like this:

```
map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds());
```